# global variable from base controller symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm trying to intercept either the rendering function or the response
to add a variable to it before loading the the view(twig).

I tried to override the default render method but it
still gives me

> Variable "myvar" does not exist in /path/to/baseAppLite.html.twig at line 10

What's wrong with my code and is there a better way ?

This is my override code in the *baseController*

```
public function render($view, array $parameters = array(), Response $response = null)
{
    $parameters = array_merge(
        $parameters,
        array(
            'myvar' => 'GlobalVar'
        )
    );
    return parent::render($view, $parameters, $response);
}
```

Usage

```
{{ myvar }}
```

---

UPDATE:
From what I can see is that the render function is not loading
because i tried echoing "render bar foo" and nothing shows up

Comment: You could use the controller render method in Twig. Then you just write one small controller action which passes that global var. I'm personally not such a huge fan of overriding methods, unless there's no other way of course :)

Comment: @Wcool sorry for my newbie question but is there an example of that way ? how can I write a method to pass the global var other than overriding the render function through the base controller ?

Comment: will write an answer soon for you :)

Comment: Your code looks fine.  Make sure your controllers are extending from your BaseController class and not the Symfony one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the render function needs to be overwritten at all to be honest.
I can think of a couple of ways that you could get access to some kind of global variable depending on how the global variable is set (or calculated).

**Twig Globals**

If it is a hardcoded variable then you could add it into your config.yml as one of the twig globals, like so...

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    # ...
    globals:
        ga_tracking: UA-xxxxx-x
```

Which can then be used like...

```
<p>The google tracking code is: {{ ga_tracking }}</p>
```

As explained here - http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html

**Twig Function**

Alternatively if you variable is related in some way to an outside service you could use a custom twig function and call that in you template.

The twig extension (with function)..

```
class AcmeExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    protected $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter(
                'get_parameter', 
                array($this, 'getParameter')
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getParameter($parameter)
    {
        if (null === $this->container) {
            return null;
        }

        return $this->container->getParameter($parameter);
        // You could also do perform some kind of action 
        // rather than just return a value
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'acme_extension';
    }
}
```

Registered as a service..

```
services:
    acme.twig.acme_extension:
        class: Acme\DemoBundle\Twig\AcmeExtension
        arguments:
            - @service_container
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

And then in your template you could use..

```
{{ get_parameter('myVar') }}
```

Or even..

```
{% set myVar = get_parameter('myVar') %}
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to my comment I have created this answer (sorry for bad grammar / spelling).

If you want to pass a var in a template that needs to be always there, you can do the following (that's how I do this anyway).

Let's say we have a PageController with CRUD methods (update, delete, show etc etc). Instead of passing that var every time (or by modifying an already defined method), we could do the following: Let Twig 'fetch' the var by rendering a controller action. Twig will call the corresponding controller and will render that variable. Let's pretend that it's a sentence in a footer that needs to be rendered by variable on each page (to keep it simple).

We could write the following action in our PageController:

```
public function renderFooterAction() {

    //Do your logic here, like retrieving the var from the database
    //or something completely different.
    //It could also be as easy as this:
    $myVar = "This is a footer sentence";

    //At the end we return a template
    return $this->render('AcmeDemoBundle:Page:footer.html.twig', array(
        'myVar' => $myVar,
    ));
}
```

The footer.html.twig page lives in YourBundle\Resources\views\Page\footer.html.twig. Depending on your needs it could be just like this (you can do everything in here like you can in a regular twig template, we're keeping it simple and only 'echoing' the variable):

```
{{ myVar }}
```

In your main template you can use the following piece of code:
    {{ render(controller('AcmeDemoBundle:Page:renderFooter')) }}

You can also pass parameters inside your template along if you need to when rendering a piece of it, like:

```
{{ render(controller('AcmeDemoBundle:Page:footer', { 'maxArticles': 5 })) }}
```

The above thing is assuming you want to do a for loop in the template the controller renders.

As you can see, rendering a controller in a template is almost like rendering a 'normal' view, instead of returning a whole template, you just create smaller files with only the controller responsible output.

Hope this explanation helped you a bit :) Of course, if you're still confused, just ask for more clarity.

**edit:** It should also be possible to directly return the variable (I think), but can't remember that so quickly. Will add that if I can find it :)